# how to Remove white space while streaming video in videoview?

Tags: android, video-streaming, fullscreen, android-videoview

I am trying to stream video in video view over HTTP. and my code is as shown below. I am getting a white space between the video. I want to play video in whole screen ... can anyone suggest what to do?

```
MediaController mc = new MediaController(VideoViewActivity.this);
mc.setAnchorView(mVideoView);
mc.setMediaPlayer(mVideoView);
Uri video = Uri.parse(path);
mVideoView.requestFocus();
mVideoView.setMediaController(mc);
mVideoView.setVideoURI(video);
mVideoView.start();
```

This is how i have coded to play the video. Below Image shows while space.
[image: image of videoview with white stripe]

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "whole screen" - are you prepared to have stuff cut away in the right and left corner?

Comment: explain more. what do you mean by "I am getting a white space between the video. I want to play video in whole screen"?

Comment: I mean when i play the video over HTTP at that time some of the space above and below the video frame comes up.. I dont know how to remove that space.. I want the video to cover whole screen.. it should not be resized according to the aspect ratio

Comment: What does the layout xml you're using look like?

Answer (score 4):

Set this for your VideoView

```
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
```

Answer (score 1):

set it programmatically

```
videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(url))

     val metrics = DisplayMetrics()
            windowManager.defaultDisplay.getMetrics(metrics)
            videoView.layoutParams = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(metrics.widthPixels, metrics.heightPixels)

videoView.start()
```